# Why can't I shutdown NSolid process? It's eating resources like nothing

Tags: node.js, nsolid

After installing NSolid in a workshop to profile/debug dummy node apps, I've noticed a spike in CPU usage and, consistently, battery power consumption and cooling fan running near full speed.

As you can imagine, this was not sustainable. I tried first by killing the NSolid main process, but it kept on spawning nevertheless.

Is there any way to control the NSolid daemon process, for example, to prevent it from starting when user session starts, and also a graceful way to shut it down when it's no longer needed?

Comment: This is a known issue that affects macOS. We are working on a fix that'll go out in v3.4.9.

Answer (score 0):

All I was left with was uninstalling. It was installed as keg-only, so I had to force uninstall dependencies first, like so:

```
brew uninstall nsolid-console --force

brew uninstall nsolid-cli --force

brew uninstall nsolid --force
```

Finally, after finding the process again on activity monitor and killing it, it was finally gone. Brute force as last resource.

I'm sure there must be a built-in mechanism that isn't intentionally made available to developers, or more likely I didn't dig deep enough in the public documentation. If anyone knows such literature, post links here by all means.

Related: should any relevant development tool's basic operation docs take more than 20 secs to find? It is my opinion that it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try reinstalling it again? we would like to properly diagnose this issue, please send us an email to support@nodesource.com to open a support ticket, we will be happy to assist you.

Regards,

Adrian